# How can I use the value of mp2t.af.pcr as a Tshark field?

Tags: udp, wireshark, rtp, mpeg

I have a wireshark capture that contains an RTP multicast stream (plus some other incidental data).

Using a Tshark command like the following, I can produce a CSV of the RTP timestamp compared with the packet capture time:

```
tshark.exe -r "capture.pcap" -Eseparator=, -Tfields -e rtp.timestamp -e frame.time_epoch -d udp.port==5000,rtp
```

This decodes the UDP packets as RTP, and successfully prints out the two fields as expected.

Now, my question: The payload of the RTP stream is an MPEG2 Transport Stream, and I also want to print the PCR value (if there is one) alongside the packet and RTP timestamps. 
In wireshark, I can see the PCR being decoded correctly, however using a command like the following:

```
tshark.exe -r "HBO HD CZ.pcap" -Eseparator=,-Tfields -e rtp.timestamp -e frame.time_epoch -e mp2t.af.pcr -d udp.port==5000,mp2t
```

...only prints out a "1" if there is a PCR oresent, not the actual value. I have also checked the .pcr_flag to confirm that these two are not exchanged, but still I see the same result.

The documentation seems to call `mp2t.af.pcr` a "Label", does this mean that Tshark is not able to use it as a field? Is there a way to generate a CSV with these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(What part of the documentation calls it a "Label"?  That's a somewhat odd description of a named field.)

The problem is that the value that Wireshark displays after "base(XXX)*300 + ext(YYY)" is calculated and displayed, but the field itself isn't given an integral type and is instead given a type that doesn't have a value.  Arguably, it should be an FT_UINT64 field and should be given a value, so that you can filter on it and can print the value in TShark.

Please file an enhancement request for this on [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org/).

Comment: The "Type" file here: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/m/mp2t.html describes that field as a Label. Thank you for your feedback - I shall file an enhancement request.

Comment: Was this ever solved?